# 'child' ' is not a child control of this parent. on inherited buttons

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance

I have a basic form that almost all forms inherit from it
and this basic form have 7 buttons (so all "child" forms have it)

it all worked fine but today I'm getting this error on all inherited buttons
the error is

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll
>
> Additional information: 'child' is not a child control of this parent.

on inherited buttons

```
 this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.button, 0);
```

in the auto generated code in the `designer.cs`

I didn't change a bit in the base form designer since yesterday

I have tried to create new buttons with the same name - did not help
and when I comment the relevant line, the button don't response

Comment: add the error to the question please.

Comment: Sorry, edited question

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue as in this old question. Recording it here if someone else faces the same.

As the error messages suggests

> Additional information: 'child' is not a child control of this parent.

The scenario is that you have inherited a form, but `button` control is missing from child form's `Controls` collection while calling

> this.Controls.SetChildIndex(this.button, 0);

In this case property `button` should be added to the `Controls` collection by the base form and the primary fix is to identify the bug why the control is missing and fix it.

If that is not possible, for some reason, secondary solution is to add missing property on `Controls` collection in your inherited form before calling designer generated code. No modification should be made in designer generated code as that will be overwritten anyway in the future.